# Drywall on concrete without gap

Tags: drywall

Traditionally drywall is lifted ~1/2" to prevent moisture from wicking into the drywall. I'm working on a media room and don't want any air gaps to maximize the STC. Will a moisture barrier, e.g. sill plate gasket, along the bottom be sufficient to prevent wicking? Are there any downsides to this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you planning to install baseboard trim?  If so, the trim should cover any gap that would have been there.

If I were very concerned about sealing the room, I would install the drywall as normal and fill the gap with caulk to provide a thermal and moisture break.

However, I wonder how much difference that gap makes considering all the other normal penetrations in a room (windows, doors, electrical outlets, etc).

Comment: I'm more concerned about sound transmission than thermals. Love the caulking idea but it'd take a ton of caulk to fill the gap under double 5/8" gypsum.

Comment: Filling that gap:  spray foam.

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to just run a pressure treated baseboard to cover the gap between floor and wallboard. Though I also used gypsum board rather than plaster board, which is less easily water-damaged.

Comment: It's so simple! Love it!

Answer (score 1):

What are you current wall / ceiling assemblies?  Hat track and sound isolation clip installs typically have the plane transitions caulked.

Walls typically have top and bottom plates which are 2x4 and 1.5" off the subfloor.  If you leave 1/2" drywall gap then you expose 1/2" of the 1.5" bottom plate - where is the air gap?

Comment: It's not really an air gap so much as a thin spot. I'm using steel studs, 16" on center, hanging from slotted track to meet code for 1.5" float required here in Colorado. My plan is 5/8" drywall for exterior wall, R13 fiberglass batt filled cavity with putty pads for receptacles, then double 5/8" drywall for the interior wall. Ceiling will be R38 fiberglass batt insulation with double 5/8" sheets of gypsum board. My goal is an STC of 67.

Comment: why would you go fiberglass over rockwool if you want STC?

Comment: One of my favorite YouTubers, Home RenoVision DIY, says the rockwool isn't worth it given the substantially higher cost.

Comment: I like Jeff Thorston but I won't put fiberglass insulation even into a rental.  It is probably $15 more a package for roxul.  It is made of rock, can't burn, still insulates while wet and provides better STC.  If it was 3x the cost of fiberglass I'd think about switching.

Answer (score 1):

STC will worse with direct contact. Concrete is porous and even dry concrete has vapor going through it. Drywall ALWAYS needs a moisture barrier between it and a porous material.